# Change color of UIButton in selected state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicolor

I have a button that when tapped changes between favorite and unfavorite. When it is tapped I change its state to selected. With this code:

```
button.selected = YES;
```

So when it is unselected it looks like this:   [image]

Then the selected version looks like this:[image]

I want the text in the selected version to be white. I know how to change the background color with this code:

```
[_favourite setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

But I want to change the elected version so that the text inside is white.

Thanks a bunch for the help in advance.

Comment: use the method setTitleColor:forState: on the button.

Answer (score 4):

Does this [UIButton API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor:forState:) accomplish what you are trying to achieve?

```
[_favourite setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```